# Develop a 2d isometric mobile game on Flash

Tags: android, ios, flash, actionscript-3, web

I'm building a game on Flash that will run on web/Android/iOS.
The game is 2d isometric.I heard that developing mobile apps on Flash sucks and the graphics looks just awful.It'd be quite uncomfortable to write code for every platfrom separately.What would you guys recommend-stay with Flash or some other platform?
By the way,do i need to build the game specially on MAC so that i can later port it on iOS?
Thanks

Comment: If you'er serious about trying something else you could check out http://www.monogame.net You can write code (identical to XNA) and it'll run on windows, linux, macs, ios, android, windows phone. Almost anywhere with re-writing barely any code. You also dont need to program it on a Mac to target iOS.

Comment: Important point - Flash doesn't work on iOS

Comment: No it does,my games work well

Answer (score 1):

> graphics looks just awful

It depends on developer only.

> What would you guys recommend-stay with Flash or some other platform?

Again, it depends on many things, including your knowledge of other languages and platforms. There're several [examples](http://gaming.adobe.com/showcase/#iOS+all+all+all) of cross-platform games but not so much to say that Flash is the one of the best platforms for game development.

I think that the main problem of Flash is performance. If you want decent FPS on mobile devices you have to use [Stage3D](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/stage3d.html). Fortunately there're several frameworks ([Flare3D](http://www.flare3d.com/), [Starling](http://gamua.com/starling/)) which help to develop faster.

So, before choosing Flash you have to be insure in performance. How to be? Test on real devices.

> By the way,do i need to build the game specially on MAC so that i can later port it on iOS?

You can develop and test using an iOS device on Windows.

Comment: Thanks,a lot.The major problem isn't graphics but rather perfomance.

Comment: @user2040131 You can get very good performance (solid 60 FPS) with GPU accelerated graphics, eg. by using the Starling Framework for your game.